# Optimal substructure and Greedy choice

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I was reading about the two properties of a greedy problem and I'm trying to understand the difference between the two below :-

- Optimal substructure property: an optimal global solution contains the optimal solutions of all its subproblems.
- Greedy choice property: a global optimal solution can be obtained by greedily selecting a locally optimal choice.

Aren't the two equivalent? The two seem like the same thing ; could you give me an example where optimal substructure is satisfied but greedy choice is not? And an example for when greedy choice is satisfied but optimal substructure is not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not equivalent:

Let's assume that we want to find the minimum vertex cover in a tree where each node has a cost(a cost of the cover is the sum of all costs of nodes in this cover). Dynamic programming can be used here: `f(v, taken)` is the minimum cost of covering a subtree rooted in `v` in such way that `v` is in the cover and `f(v, not taken)` is the minimum cost of covering this subtree without taking `v`. Optimal substructure property holds true because we can solve subproblems optimally(that is, find an optimal solution for each subtree) and then combine them to find the global optimal solution. However, greedy choice property does not hold true here: picking a vertex with the smallest cost until all edges are covered does not always yield an optimal result.

It is possible that greedy choice property holds true but the optimal substructure property does not if it is not possible to define what a subproblem is. For example, Huffman code construction algorithm always merges two smallest subtrees(and yields an optimal solution), so it is a greedy algorithm, but it is not clear what a subproblem is, so it doesn't make much sense to talk about the first property at all.

Comment: I would define a subproblem this way: The subproblem is a new problem instance where the two subtrees of lowest frequency have been merged to one subtree.  Thus it is strictly smaller than the original problem.

Comment: I see almost everywhere that greedy algorithms require both the optimal substructure property and the greedy choice property to guarantee the optimal solution. I take from this that that's not true, that only the greedy choice property is required. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

For future readers who may not be familiar with vertex cover nor dynamic programming, the phrasing of those definitions does make it sound similar.

I think a useful way to rephrase *greedy choice* is that the optimal solution will always contain the first choice chosen by the greedy algorithm, although it doesn't necessarily have to be the first choice in the said optimal solution **--> this is why they are different because although something may be optimal and display the greedy choice property you haven't proven that at every step the current most optimal solution was made. Think [Prim's MST](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/prims_spanning_tree_algorithm.htm) on a weighted graph: you can start at any vertex but that means that the algorithm may choose different edges at each step for these two solutions but they always choose the edge from any given vertex with the lowest weight, thus they have the greedy choice property. But you haven't proven anything about the whole solution at each step is absolutely optimal, just that choose the greediest option.

That's why they're different, although greedy choice can lead to optimal substructure, it doesn't prove that it has optimal substructure. Common arguments to prove optimal substructure are the *exchange argument* and the *stay-ahead argument* which build off of the knowledge the algorithm displays the greedy choice property.